# InvalidCastExeption in LINQ to XML

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting, linq-to-xml

I am using LINQ to XML to take some data from resources , and here I have a function, where I take some values and then I create a new object (Type Translation), so when I call the function I get a Translation object. By now I have this code:

```
     Public Shared Function RetrieveTranslation(ByVal file As String) As List(Of clsTranslation)
    Dim valuetrans = From vl In XElement.Load(file).Elements("data") Select (New clsTranslation With {.Filename = file, .Value = vl.Element("value").Value, .TranslationId = vl.Attribute("name").Value})
    Return valuetrans
End Function
```

The problem is that with this code I got this error:
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,clsTranslation]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[clsTranslation]'.

Do you know the way to cast it?
Thanks in advance,

Alfonso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were compiling with Option Strict on, you'd have found this out at compile time.

You don't cast it - you call `ToList()` on the result, to create a `List<clsTranslation>` from the `IEnumerable<clsTranslation>`.

(I'd also advise you to ditch the `cls` prefix; it goes against the .NET naming conventions.)

That would leave:

```
Public Shared Function RetrieveTranslation(ByVal file As String) _
        As List(Of Translation)
    Return (From vl In XElement.Load(file).Elements("data") _
            Select (New Translation With { _
                               .Filename = file, _
                               .Value = vl.Element("value").Value, _
                               .TranslationId = vl.Attribute("name").Value}) _
           ).ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: thank you very much, it was that! thank you also for the advices ;-)